# What is the difference between $\mathcal{O}_X$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

I would like to understand is the difference between the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X$ and the fiber bundle $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ which can be written as $\bigotimes_n \mathcal{O}_X(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. $=\mathbb{P}^1$ for all purposes.

So to start with $\mathcal{O}_X$ which is the same as $\mathcal{O}_X(0)$ and this denotes the trivial line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ or the structure sheaf of regular functions. In what way is $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ different then and in what sense it is dual to $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$?

The other question is why can any, say rank 2 vector bundle $E$ be written as the tensor sum $E = \mathcal{O}(n) \oplus \mathcal{O}(n)$?

I would like for an us much as possible intuitive answer since I struggle a lot with these concepts.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. What is your definition of $O(1)$? Anyway, one difference is that $O$ is just the sheaf of regular functions, so its only global sections are the constant functions. By contrast, $O(1)$ has more global sections. Is that a helpful thing to say?

Comment: As for the second question, this is called the Birkhoff or Birkhoff-Grothendieck theorem. There is a short proof that you can find by googling.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}$ is just the structure sheaf. $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the dual of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ the tautological line bundle.

Comment: It seems like they're dual by definition for you, so I'm not sure what the second part of your first "?" can really mean. Also, do you want to write $E \simeq \mathcal O(n) \oplus \mathcal O(m)$? It doesn't seem to be like you can get it to be so nice.

Comment: @Hoot, I m not sure what you exactly mean. My main question is to understand, maybe through some example, the first question I asked.

Comment: Did you have the Correspondence between divisor classes and line bundles already?

Comment: Hi, no I have not seen this actually. Any help/reference?